# Emberjs. How to Access the model in the Router coming from #link-to

Tags: ember.js

I am developing a simple demo with ember that reads from google news rss.

My current url is:

path/:query

Router.map:

```
  this.resource('query', {path:':query_done'});
  this.resource('time', {path:':query_done/:time_interval'});
```

From this view I am going with #link-to to url/:query/:time route:

```
{{input type="text" id="timebox" placeholder="time" value=timetext }}   {{#link-to 'time' timetext}}Time Interval{{/link-to}}
```

How could I access the model retrieve from url/:query to use it now?

```
App.QueryTime = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function (params) {
???? 
});
```

Comment: if you go to the link-to documentation, you'll find that if you provide a model in the link-to, the 'model' hook in the route won't be executed. If for instance, instead sending the model, you send the model.id, the 'model' hook will be executed, but you'll then need to return the model object again in the 'model' hook.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea of how could I send the model.id then in this case?